# Does the Socrata API have any facilities for accessing comments?

Tags: socrata, soda

The Socrata API provides access to dataset points as well as metadata about the datasets at large. However I didn't find any facility in their API for accessing the *comments* on datasets. I wanted to double-check that I'm not simply missing something or that it's not just not in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the answer to this is no, unfortunately.

Comment: Correct, unfortunately your best option is probably just to screen scrape the Comments sidebar.